# How do i get fieldvalues in the Body of a javascript generated email

Tags: javascript, html-email

i can produce an email with javascript and smtp.js.

I would however like to add fieldvalues from the form into the body and cannot find the right syntax.

there is an inputfield for email and a field for a number,
i tried :
var email=Form.email.value;
var body = " Well that was easy!! "+email;

Subject: "Sending Email using javascript",
Body: "here i would like to add fieldvalues",
})

Can anyone please give a hint, i do not use javascript very often.
Seems i will have to start learning. . .

Regards,
Jan

Here is the code i used:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
  <title>Send Mail</title>
  <script src=
    "https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendEmail() {
      Email.send({
        Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        Username: "sender@email_address.com",
        Password: "Enter your password",
        To: 'receiver@email_address.com',
        From: "sender@email_address.com",
        Subject: "Sending Email using javascript",
        Body: "Well that was easy!!",
      })
        .then(function (message) {
          alert("mail sent successfully")
        });
    }
  </script>
</head>
  
<body>
  <form method="post">
<!-- here i would like to enter an e-mail-address that i want to use in the e-mail that is sent -->
    
    E-Mail: <input class="input2" type="text" name="email"><br>
    
    <input type="button" value="Send Email" 
        onclick="sendEmail()" />
  </form>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: You need to post more of your code, i.e. the HTML this JS is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

I mixed up `var` and `let`.

so far it is sending an email and i can enter some text from the inputfield
with:

```
let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
```

Now i need to get an array in property "To" so i can sand to 2 email-addresses.

regards,
Jan